# k2 limit number of items that can be created by user

Tags: joomla, limit, joomla-k2

I'm building a K2-website where I'd like to limit the cration of items per user.
In this case there are "schools" with f.i. "news", "pictures", "events".

- school (max. 1)

  - news (> 1)
  - pictures (> 1)
  - events (> 1)

There should be only one K2-school-item per school and multiple items per sub-category-items.

Is this possible to realize?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Comment: I know this post is old. But have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

1- Changing the K2 core
2- Modifying the template to only display the first K2 item for special categories (such as schools).